# crashing MacBook Pro :(

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic, cpu

I have a MacBook Pro from 2010 with 2.4 Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo and 4 GB of RAM.

Lately I am getting many kernel panics when my MacBook Pro is under high load, such as when copying, playing video's, editing etc.

Sometimes, it won't start anymore, it would just beep, and give a blackscreen. Hitting the powerbutton a few times helps.

Sometimes during crashes I get crazy colour patterns on-screen. Making me suspect the video card. Another clue is that the MacBook Pro sometimes crashes when it is moved.

Can it be the RAM (which would be nice since it is replaceble). Is it worth a try? The log is included below.

Help is much apreciated!

```
Fri Mar 28 20:40:17 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0x2abf6a): Kernel trap at 0x00134f9b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x8001003b, CR2: 0x00134f9b, CR3: 0×00100000, CR4: 0×00000668
EAX: 0x090bcf80, EBX: 0x0908d400, ECX: 0×00000000, EDX: 0x08ef6c00
CR2: 0x00134f9b, EBP: 0x52bb3f28, ESI: 0×00000001, EDI: 0x00134f9b
EFL: 0×00010246, EIP: 0x00134f9b, CS:  0×00000008, DS:  0×00000010
Error code: 0×00000010
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the OS?

Comment: I am afraid of doing that because when it crashes because of too much pressure on the machine... I have nothing. Moreover, I am suspecting hardware because moving or hitting sometimes leads to crashes...

Comment: Can I test the fans? Maybe they fail resulting into a crash

Comment: Start in safe mode (hold shit during start up) and see if it is ok then.